# Store result from api call React native

Tags: react-native

How can I store the recipe name from this api call into a state variable or some other variable to be used further down in the render

```
{
        this.props.recipeList.recipeList.filter((recipe) => recipe.recipeName === search).map(recipe => {
          return <Recipe
            name={recipe.recipeName}
            numberOfServings={recipe.numberOfServings}
            key={'recipe-' + recipe.recipeId}
          />
        })
      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As this is performed within `render`, avoid modifying the component state.

I would recommend declaring a variable at the top of your `render` method and then assigning it in your `map` call. This, of course, assumes that `filter` will only ever return a single result.

Something like:

```
render() {
  let name;

  ....

  {
    this.props.recipeList.recipeList.filter((recipe) => recipe.recipeName === search).map(recipe => {
      name = recipe.recipeName; // this bit
      return <Recipe
        name={recipe.recipeName}
        numberOfServings={recipe.numberOfServings}
        key={'recipe-' + recipe.recipeId}
      />
    })
  }

....
```

Comment: Is there a way to pop out of the render and set the state?

Comment: What's the use case?

Comment: I want to use the variable name that you created... make it an array, and first check if it is empty, if not, I want to display all the names in it.

Comment: Does the content of the recipeList change during the lifetime of the component? If not, I would put that array in the state and populate it in componentDidMount